# I can't catch the "range is too small for min.n" error

Tags: r

I'm trying to catch a "range is too small for min.n" error while plotting multiple plots in a for loop using ggplot2 library:

```
for (cod in unique(src$codes)) {
    ...
    p1 <- try(
            ggplot(data = df) +
            ...
           , silent = TRUE)

    print(p1)
}
```

But I always get the error. How can I simply avoid to get the error and continue the loop?

Thank you.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example, it is hard to help without specific test case

Comment: I simply can't attach my entire data set in order to make the example reproducible. And also I'm not able to select a subset of it, because I don't know what rows raise the error.
It's just a question about how properly use the try function in ggplot statements and Marcelo just answered it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error will only be reported when  `p1` is evaluated/printed. You should use:

```
p1 <-  ggplot(data = df) +
        ...

try(print(p1), silent = TRUE)
```